# How to run migration on only specific database name when using fluentMigrator

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-migration, fluent-migrator

We are using `.NET4.5`, `SQL2012` and `FluentMigrator` [to control our database migrations](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Dealing-with-Multiple-Database-Types). We are running multiple databases in our solution and we need to run some data inserts into some databases but not the others.

**How can I run some database migrations based on specific database name?**

Comment: This Q/A saved me a lot of time and I wish it get more upvotes. Maybe add some context like "FM runs all migrations it can find in a given dll", "the Tag attributes are useful for specific migrations but their purpose is certainly not to be widespread" and "the documentation tells you how to target different DBMS's, but there is nothing about different DB's" so it is clear that the documentation is anemic as opposed to you not having done proper search before asking.

Comment: @RenaudGauthier Hi Renaud, reason this Q is not getting upvotes is not phrasing (title corresponds to what is in the answer) but question being very niche, just look at the views... also I don't care enough TBH... Helping people on SO is not very rewarding so I 'retired'..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have introduced this class that controls which databases it should run on. So rather when inheriting from `Migration` you would now inherit from `OnlyRunOnSpecificDatabaseMigration`:

**One note!: It does fallback onto default behavior (to run migration) if there are no databases listed in `DatabaseNamesToRunMigrationOnList` - which some might find counter-intuitive**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Migrations
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using FluentMigrator;
    using FluentMigrator.Infrastructure;

    public abstract class OnlyRunOnSpecificDatabaseMigration : Migration
    {
        public abstract List<string> DatabaseNamesToRunMigrationOnList { get; }

        private bool DoRunMigraton(IMigrationContext context)
        {
            return this.DatabaseNamesToRunMigrationOnList == null ||
                   this.DatabaseNamesToRunMigrationOnList.Contains(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(context.Connection).InitialCatalog);
        }

        public override void GetUpExpressions(IMigrationContext context)
        {
            if (this.DoRunMigraton(context))
            {
                base.GetUpExpressions(context);
            }
        }

        public override void GetDownExpressions(IMigrationContext context)
        {
            if (this.DoRunMigraton(context))
            {
                base.GetDownExpressions(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
public class RiskItems : OnlyRunOnSpecificDatabaseMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

        Execute.Sql(@"update [Items] set  
                    CanBeX = 
                    case when exists(select 1 from [SomeTable] where Key = [Items].Key and position like 'Factor%') then 1 else 0 end");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {

    }

    public override List<string> DatabaseNamesToRunMigrationOnList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string> {"my_database_name"};
        }
    }
}
```